# How to fill in UK Visa application that requires 2 years of addresses, when child is less than 2?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, children

I am applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa for my daughter who is less than 2 years old. I am stuck at this page of the form:

> **Previous address history**
>
> You must provide the addresses that you have lived in the past 2 years.

I filled out that she has been living at the current address for 20 months. I'm not sure how to get the application process to go forward.

Comment: You mean the online form won't let you proceed unless you provide dated addresses for the last 2 years? Just put her as having lived at her current address for 2 years.

Comment: Where did her mom live for the four months before she was born?

Comment: Exactly , my baby is 6 months old and I'm stuck there too. Can any one suggest an alternative.

Comment: In similar situation, what did you do @CraniumRat ?

Answer (score 12):

The form automatically requires two years of addresses to proceed with the application, to get around this simply say she has lived there for two years. This is a design flaw of the page and is the only thing that can be done, they will be able to see how old she is elsewhere in the application, and is only a four month difference.

Comment: This looks sensible. I'm in similar situation right now, did anyone try this actually ?